# Computed property in Vue does not change when updating its data through an event listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a select input that has multiple options and I have already written a function that finds the selected option and dispatches a custom event with the selected value contained in it.

My custom event is called "newOptionSelected".

Now I have a different component written in VueJS and this is its script section:

```
export default {
data()
{
    return {
        option: null,
    }
},
computed: {
    selectedOption()
    {
        return this.option
    },
},
mounted()
{
    document.addEventListener("newOptionSelected", function(event){
        this.option = event.detail.option;
        console.log(this.option);
    });
}
}
```

However, this doesn't work and selectedOption does not get updated when I select a new option. I am using VueJS by adding it as a JS script to my files and I'm not using Vue CLI. Any idea how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: why dont you use @newOptionSelected="updateOption" on the componenet that is emitted that event

Comment: @NoName: It doesn't work. Probably because they are in separate files and this isn't an SPA, I'm not sure. This is the error that it throws:

Property or method "updateOption" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. If I forgot to clarify it, my main file (which contains the select input) is a blade template in Laravel and I'm trying to pass its change to the Vue component.

Comment: can you please show how you are emitting the event?

Comment: You need to add a watcher to 'watch' value changes. Check this out: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is in the scope or the listener's `function`'s `this` vs potential `arrow function`'s `this`, where the former has its own `this` and does not affect the `option` of Vue's `data`? Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions